# NOT NULL constraint failed: history.user_id

Tags: django, null, constraints

I am new to Django and I am trying to learn by practicing with some project but I am stuck with this problem, I want to return the information of the History model to the authenticated user according to its id_user. The problem appears when the user gives the submit of the form.

The message that he gives me is this:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: history.user_id
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class History(models.Model):

   DAY35 = '35 days'
   DAY45 = '45 days'
   HISTORY_DAYS = (
       (DAY35, '35 days'),
       (DAY45, '45 days'),
   )

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   amount = models.FloatField(default=10)
   days = models.CharField(
       max_length=7,
       choices=HISTORY_DAYS,
        default=DAY35,
    )

   def is_upperclass(self):
       return self.days in (self.DAY35, self.DAY45)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required    
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import HistoryForm
from .models import History


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class HistoryCreate(CreateView):
    model = History
    fields = ['amount', 'days']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('history')
    form_class = HistoryForm
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import MiningHistory


class HistoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = History

        fields = ['amount', 'days']
        widgets = {
            'amount': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'x', 'placeholder':'0.00'}),
            'days': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'x'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A History instance must have a non null user field. However you are not specifying the user related the History object you're creating.
In case you dont want to add the user, update you're model's user field :

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

If you want to associate the user field with the logged in user, update your views :

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class HistoryCreate(CreateView):
    model = History
    fields = ['amount', 'days']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('history')
    form_class = HistoryForm
    def form_valid(self, form_class ):
        form_class.instance.user= self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Don't forget to add user to your form fields.

PS : Don't add user to your views modifiable fields. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) for more details.